# why db execution doesn't stops even if I stops the web browser?

Tags: asp.net, webserver

Taking a scenario, If I insert something in db using any form of web application 
and stops the browser in between , the process of db query execution still continues why is it so ?

can something be done to stop db execution whenever browser stops responding ?

Comment: Command is execute on data base server and browser run on the client machine. 
When user hit submit button on form all form data send to server for further process. 
Browser close is a client site event and it will not transmit any data or command to server  to stop the insert command.

This is all about HTTP client server architecture.

Comment: Thank you , for your kind reply. Makes sense Once a connection is hindered between the client and server . Server independently continues what it is asked to do.   But thinking another way round if I maintain sessions , Then also Db query doesn't return anything . Why so?

Comment: "if I maintain sessions" . How  can you maintain session between HTTP requests.